# Pegar posição de view na tela e aplicar em outra view

Tags: java, android, android-layout

estou tentando fazer um efeito de transição quando abro um `DialogFragment` mas para isso preciso que a foto(`CircleImageView`) do `DialogFragment` esteja no mesmo lugar que a foto da `Activity` que o abre. Caso não fique claro vou explicar com as imagens:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa é a imagem que quero usar como base de posicionamento para a outra do `DialogFragment`. Ao clicar nessa foto abre-se um o `DialogFragment` com esta tela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Desconsiderem os botões**, o meu foco é apenas a imagem. Como faço para posicionar essa imagem exatamente no mesmo lugar que a outra programaticamente?

Comment: Primeiro eu pensei: se a segunda imagem tem o fundo branco porque ele não cria uma imagem do tamanho da primeira com o fundo branco? Depois pensei: como garantir que a primeira imagem vai sempre estar no mesmo lugar em função das diversas resoluções de tela entre os dispositivos?

Comment: Exatamente, não consegui recriar o mesmo layout pois o primeiro é um ´header´ de um ´DrawerLayout´ e acabaria não ficando nas mesmas proporções.

Comment: Este link lhe mostra como posicionar a imagem. Não sei como garantir que a primeira imagem sempre estará no mesmo lugar.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418726/android-setting-x-y-of-image-programmatically
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535648/how-can-i-dynamically-set-the-position-of-view-in-android
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19328756/set-position-of-programmatically-created-imageview-android

Comment: Primeiro você teria que centralizar de acordo ao dispositivo, para que no `fragment` permaneça centralizada.

Comment: Eu quero posicionar a segunda foto de acordo com a primeira e não o contrário.

Comment: @BrunoRomualdo então, tente posicionar sua foto dentro de um `LinearLayout`, ai você usa esse `Linear` no seu `fragment`.

Comment: Apenas entenda que não tem como colocar os dois na mesma posição usando o xml, por isso no final da pergunta está escrito programaticamente.

Answer (score 1):

Use esta biblioteca que já contém esse tipo de tratamento: 
https://github.com/lgvalle/Material-Animations

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Mas você pode(e até deve) contextualizar e exemplificar sua resposta, de formar que os links sejam apenas referencia. Respostas apenas com links não são muito bem aceitas no site.

Comment: E um exemplo de uso, pode adicionar?

Comment: Olá `@Anderson`, já vi uma vez essa biblioteca mas não usei por não ter um exemplo de como usá-la em um  `DialogFragment`, como o `@Diegofm` disse voce não tem um exemplo? ja ajudaria muito.

Comment: Agora que deu uma olhada na documentação esta falando que só funciona a partir do `Lollipop` pra cima, não adianta.